# Angular fetching data (http - messagebird)

Tags: javascript, angular, messagebird

I am trying to fetch the conversations from my messagebird api, I tried in postman and all is good but when I'm trying to get from my angular project, that gives me an error, this is my code:

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private service: WaServiceService) { }

  fetchCharacters() {
    this.service.getConversations().subscribe(
      (data) => {
        console.log(data); 
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error(error);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class WaServiceService {
  private apiUrl = 'https://conversations.messagebird.com/v1/conversations?status=all&offset=0&limit=20';
  private apiKey = 'AccessKey abc123';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getConversations(): Observable<any> {
    const url = `${this.apiUrl}`;
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', `${this.apiKey}`);

    return this.http.get(url, { headers });
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

[image: postman image]

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it's a CORS issue, access from different origin is not allowed (this is why it's working with Postman, and not with Angular, see: [XMLHttpRequest cannot load XXX No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553500/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-xxx-no-access-control-allow-origin-header)).
Also, all Angular code is public, so you should never include your API key on frontend.

You need to make messagebird request from the server (it depends on your server, check [SDK examples](https://developers.messagebird.com/libraries), instead from the frontend.

So, from Angular, you make request to your server and send some parameters and data to make a request, and then server uses that data and parameters and then makes a request to messagebird, and returns data to Angular service.

Angular service:

```
this.http.get('YOUR SERVER URL', someDataForRequest);
```

your server ([Node.js example](https://github.com/messagebird/messagebird-nodejs) inspired pseudocode):

```
const apiKey = 'AccessKey abc123';

const messagebird = require('messagebird').initClient('apiKey');

makeRequest(someDataForRequest) {

    // list conversations
    // In this case 20 is limit and 0 is offset
    messagebird.conversations.list(20, 0, function(err, response) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        console.log(response);
        
        // return data to frontend
        return response;

    });

}
```